# Нужна ли запятая перед "что" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, редактура

Нужна ли запятая перед "что" в предложении "Не знаю что еще ответить."

Кусок текста, из которого дан пример:

Наверное, ты во всем права, если мыслить с бытовой точки зрения, из этой плоскости. **Не знаю что еще ответить.**

Answer (score 1):

В этой теме надо различать придаточные предложения, которые обособляются и устойчивые обороты без обособления

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

Устойчивый оборот тесно связан со сказуемым, и Розенталь дает ориентировочный **список** таких выражений. Но **в пограничных случаях** (при достаточно распространенном обороте) автор может сам решить, какой вариант ему выбрать, так как они различаются **постановкой ударения.**

(1) Наверное, ты во всем права, если мыслить с бытовой точки зрения, из этой плоскости. **Не знаю, // что ещЁ ответить.**

(2) Наверное, ты во всем права, если мыслить с бытовой точки зрения, из этой плоскости. **Не знАю что еще ответить.**

В первом варианте делается пауза и ставятся два ударения, но логически выделено **наречие "еще"**. Во втором варианте мы имеем простое предложение с логическим ударением **на глаголе "не знаю".**

Это уже авторский выбор (что хотите подчеркнуть).